# Would this be copyright or patent issue

Tags: copyright, client-relations

I'll keep it simple. As a hobby I do photo edits for people on Instagram to help them promote things, in this case an up-and-coming body builder/power lifter. For the most part he has always just reposted them on his page and ask me to make edits with specific information to promote events. Well  recently I created an image for him, and now he's saying he wants to put it on a t-shirt and then distribute.

My question is: is there anything I can gain from this even though I never claimed a patent or copyright on my images?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking to gain? I'm assuming you are looking for compensation for designs you've already done? Typically when you hand over a design it belongs to the client, what they want to do with it is up to them. If he never paid you (because you did the work for free?) and now you want to be compensated, having a conversation with him about what you want seems like the first step. A lesson for future jobs you take on is to make these agreements up-front.

Comment: please add punctuation to your post. As for what to do, do you want money? if so, ask for money.

Comment: This question is all but illegible, and it’s extremely unclear what you’re actually trying to ask. Please edit your question to make it easier to read (adding punctuation and paragraphs as well as structuring it as actual text, rather than one long line of incoherent stream-of-consciousness goes a **long** way), and clarify what precisely it is you’re asking. @Vicki’s comment should help you see what it is that’s unclear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about law.

Answer (score 1):

Lesson 1: Always have a contract. That contract should specify who owns the copyright to the source image and who owns the copyright to the final image, and who gets paid for what when the photo is used elsewhere.

Since you don't, you have to wing it. If the client provided the original photo, the copyright of the original photo belongs to the client (provided it doesn't belong to a third party).

If all you did was touch up the photo or add some cute filters, IMHO you haven't done anything worth copyrighting, and you're stuck.

If you altered it significantly — if you've added text, cropped, changed the color balance, etc. — then that's something you can copyright.

In this case, I would find out how many shirts he plans on distributing, and if it's for one event or an ongoing promotion. If it's a one-off, ask for a lump sum. If it's ongoing and he'll be reprinting the shirt, ask for royalties.